# Creating an "Import External Data" admin page in Sitecore

Tags: c#, import, sitecore, sitecore6

As part of the development for a website powered by Sitecore 6.3.1, I will need to implement a way to manage data from a couple of external sources in Sitecore.

To accomplish this, the simplest solution appears to be to import the external data into Sitecore as content items with a special workflow that will export them back to the external data source when they reach the final state.

I came across [this article](http://www.webdatasource.com/2008/10/importing-and-updating-data-with-sitecore/) which details the code required to import data into Sitecore, but I am uncertain as to the best way to make this functionality accessible.

Considering that this process will probably (but not certainly) only be done once after the site is completed, what approach (page/Sitecore item/shell application/?) could I take to provide a way for a developer user to perform the import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the `Sitecore` classes are available even in web forms outside of Sitecore.  I created a separate .aspx file and used `Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master")` to interact with Sitecore's database.